# Java Reconstruct data structure using lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

I have a following relationship: Class A has a List of objects of Class B, Class B has an object of Class C and an object of Class D. Class C has a String E, Class D has an integer F.Class C to Class D is an one-to-many relationship.

Given a map of `<String, List<A>>`, how can I reconstruct it to a map of `<F, E>`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `String` in `Map<String, List<A>>` related to the output? I assume that you want to get every pair `<F, E>` from the original map right? So this might help

```
Map<String, List<A>> input;
input.values().stream()
     .flatMap(Collection::stream)
     .map(a -> a.getListB()) // extract list B from A
     .flatMap(Collection::stream) // Here you get all B instances
     .collect(
         toMap(
            b -> b.getD().getF(), b -> b.getC().getE(), 
            (e1, e2) -> ??? // Here you should define your own merge function if there are two B instances has same F values
          )
     );
```

Comment: Thanks. The String in the original input doesn't matter.I have the output initiated as Map<F, E> before the lambda expression starts. Is it possible to populate the Map<F, E> by using a foreach or something like that after you get all the B instance?

Comment: Assume you already defined `Map<F,E> result`. Then after get all B instance, all you have to do is use `.forEach(b -> result.put(b.getD().getF(), b.getC().getE())`

Comment: Glad it helps you